# How to implement android:inputType="textPassword" using HTML, JS and CSS

Tags: javascript, android, html, input

How to create android type password input using HTML, JS and CSS.

So that when user type, they will be able to see the preview of the character last typed for some period of time before it getting masked?

Thought of doing this using setTimeout functionality but didn't worked out.

Any suggestions or reference to do this?

Comment: use an Interval instead?

Comment: but if user type again inbetweeen the interval?

Comment: @PiccazaDe clear the interval and start it over

Comment: @Albert little more detail on the work flow will really help.